# What's a common name for creating and removing objects?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm about to name a method in my software. It's going to perform two tasks that are, more or less, inseparable from each other. The first one is to create a table in a database. The second one is to remove. It might sound pointless to do that but the aim of the test is to verify whether that can be done.

The currently picked name for the method is *TemporaryTableCreationAndRemoval*. However, I'm not happy about the last part, so I wonder what'd be a good term to describe both the process of creation and, subsequently following, the process of removal.

Supposing that such an action is called *to shazoo* (i.e. *to shazoo* = *to create something and then, inevitably and directly, remove it*), the name of the method would be *TemporaryTableShazoo*.

Comment: I think *shazoo* does nicely. Also, *TempTableVerification* describes what you just said.

Comment: @KitFox *Shazoo* is just a made-up word I heard on "*Family Guy*", so that's not quite right, hehe. Verify is the point of the test but I'd like to be explicit on what's being done in order to verify. Hence the need for a verb describing creation-then-removal.

Comment: I can't think of a word for create-and-remove at the moment, though with my advancing age this does not mean there is not one. Unless the general public will see the verification process, I'd use KitFox's suggestion of "TempTableVerification" (or your own TempTableShazoo, and explain how the verification is performed in a comment in the method.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as currently worded because it is about the naming of identifiers in a computer program. However, it might be salvageable if somewhat reworded to place emphasis on English proper, then relegating the programming-relevant portion to an example at the end of the main question. It might also be something more appropriate to the Programmers SE site.

Comment: The usual terms for such methods are [***Creators***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(computer_science)) and [***Destructors***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_(computer_science)). So your name should probly invoke them both.

Comment: @JohnLawler Oh, principally it's a great suggestion. In this case, however, that might to a terrible confusion, since constructors and destructors are used in object oriented programming as the first/last methods to be called when instantiating and garbage collecting objects. In my case, however, I only make and delete a table. In nHybernate and EF, your remark would be very true, though, so point taken.

Comment: @tchrist Actually, it's not at all about computer programming. It's about a concise way of expressing the process of creation and deletion of pretty much anything. If such a term exists, that is. I'm certain that if I haven't provided the background of my question, someone would vote me down for sure referring to a vague and troll'ish question.

Comment: So you’re writing a ***condestructor*** as an exercise in [Eschatology and Genesis](http://www.wolfewiki.com/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=WolfeWiki.ThePlay) but in the opposite order? :)

Comment: @tchrist Kind of, yes, I do... Although not in the opposite order but rather straightforward. Also, while I love *condestructor*, I wonder if the term can confuse since it's constituted of a conflicting connotation to the prefix *con*, consequently containing it's meaning as *with*.   :)

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you should favor descriptive method and variable names over shorter, less descriptive names. Trying to make your method name shorter doesn't always improve readability. There are also naming conventions about method names starting with verbs, but that goes outside the question.

All of that being said, something like `testTableCreationAndDeletion` seems like a reasonable name to me.

Comment: Except for the *test* prefix, I do agree. I'll never jeopardize the readability of my code in favor of shortening the methods' nomenclature, of course. However, as a secondary aim, under the condition that the readability is maintained, I see no harm (and in fact a lot of good) in making the text more concise.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Fair enough. I started the method name with *test* because *that's what it's doing* and method names, generally, should start with verbs. But it's up to you.

Comment: A bit off-topic: When we switched to nUnit 2.0, there's actually [a recommendation on the providers web site](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=attributes&r=2.6) that a test method should be **attributed** as a Test or TestCase etc. That's a new paradigm opposing that of the former version where the recognition of test fixtures was reliant on the suffix *test*, which was a necessity since attributes weren't introduced until .NET 4.   :)

Comment: I'm not a .NET programmer, but I guess it depends on how you're using these tests: is it really a function, or is it more like an object or a data structure? It sounds like it's a function, which I still think should start with a verb, but that's more up to yours and your company's naming conventions than it is any real grammar.